# Solidity opcode error when sending coin to an address

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

So I get the error below when attempting to send the coins to another address, and with the debugger, I can't figure out where's the problem. What am I doing wrong? (I just started learning solidity a few days ago).

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

```
contract HelloWorld {

    mapping (address => uint) balances;
    address owner;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function HelloWorld() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 1500;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getBalances(address addr) returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

    function getOwner() returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool success) {

        if(balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false; // Check amount of coins

        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;

        Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error with your Contract from question deployed to testrpc, for example, with the last stable version of compiler:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it by replacing msg.sender with the owner address var declared in the constructor. Does anyone know why now it works?

```
contract HelloWorld {

    mapping (address => uint) balances;
    address owner;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function HelloWorld() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 1500;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

    function getOwner() returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool success) {

        if(amount > balances[owner]) return false; // Check balance

        balances[owner] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;

        Transfer(owner, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you are probably using Solidity compiler version 0.4.0, whereas @ViktorBaranov tested the same code with version 0.4.13. Although this seems to be very simple code, it might be that the earlier compiler had a bug.